# What are these CSS selectors tr.odd and tr.even?

Tags: css

I am maintaining a legacy site that was on a CMS 10 years ago. I found the following bit of code that apparently stripes tables for readability.

```
 .content tr.odd {
     color: #6e6e6e;
     background-color: #ffffff;
 }
 .content tr.even {   
     color: #6e6e6e;
     background-color: #ffeac1;
 }
```

Google was no help; all it talked about was the usual `tr:nth-child` form.  I am wondering if this is some sort of "magic" CSS selectors *that work like they sound*... or was somebody really hitting the whiskey?

Edit: Or is this some sort of deprecated form?  What would the history of that be? Why didn't they use the normal and widely documented method?

Comment: yep that is valid looking for a `tr` with either `odd`/`even` classes inside something withi `content`

Comment: @Hosch250 I certainly did google it, and looked through the first two pages.  There was no reference I could see to the tr.odd and tr.even method, but a great deal of reference to the `nth-child` method.  Did I need to disclose all this in the question to avoid the downvotes?

Comment: Trivial understanding of CSS selectors tells you the answer. That's what the downvotes are about.

Comment: @Hosch250 I got blindsided by the very concept of painstakingly putting `class=even` etc. in every single table row, which seems impossibly awkward and would disintegrate at the first table edit.  I was imagining this would be some sort of automatic method like `nth-child`, which I thought most peculiar, hence my question.

Comment: Retracted my DV because that's a reasonable question, and because you edited your question to reflect that, and knowing the state of the web, that's actually something I can see the web standards people doing. However, as a general rule, this is actually good programming by a lot of people's standards (hey, they actually used well-named classes to do their styling).

Comment: Also, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child, it wasn't supported at all until IE 9. Turns out this is actually reasonable programming if you need to support older browsers (at work, we have to support IE 8, and we like to support IE 6, so you can imagine the crap we have to deal with).

Comment: @Hosch250 Sounds like you've got a hell of an answer there.  The method would also make a lot more sense if this was generated by authoring software instead of manually edited. Manually it would be a train wreck, add a row and all the ones below are wrong.  (I am a dreamweaver holdout).

Comment: We use ASP.NET MVC, so we can, say, loop over datasets and generate custom HTML server-side with the full power of C#. Blake's answer+comments has everything, so I won't post a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is creating the tr elements would have to apply those classes. That is, it's just styling something like this:

```
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="even">...</tr>
```

However, you could instead use the nth-child selector with the keywords "odd" and "even", which might be more along the lines of what your question was asking about:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

In the 2nd case, you wouldn't need to explicitly apply "odd" and "even" classes like in the 1st example.

Comment: Interesting.  Did the `nth-child()` form not exist 9-10 years ago?  I'm trying to understand why they'd use this technique.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be consistently supported at that time. It's a CSS3 selector, and it doesn't look like it was supported until IE9 and Firefox 3.5, which would have been released around that time (Chrome's original release would also be in that timeframe)

Answer (score -1):

"One way to improve the readability of large tables is to color alternating rows. For example, the table below has a light gray background for the even rows and white for the odd ones."

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html